# Query regarding an alegbraic inequality

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Do we have any inequality of the type $(a-b)^q \geq C_q(a^q-b^q),$ where $q>0$ and $a,b$ are real numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $q > 1$, take $a = x + 1$ and $b = x$ where $x > 0$. Then, $1 = 1^q \ge C_q((x+1)^q-x^q) > C_q q x^{q-1}$.

Regardless of the value of $C_q$, this inequality is violated for sufficiently large $x$.

For $0 < q < 1$, you can show that $C_q = \dfrac{1}{q}$ works if you restrict $a > b > 0$. Without this restriction, one of $a$, $b$, or $a-b$ could be negative, which makes defining $a^q$, $b^q$, or $(a-b)^q$ tricky.

Comment: Are you aware of any inequality of the form $(a-b)^q \leq C(a^q-b^q)$